# change the selected value to upper case in the richtextbox in vb 2008

Tags: vb.net

i need to change the selected value to upper case in the richtextbox   i use the code

```
 Dim tou As String
        Dim tot As String

        tou = RichTextBox1.SelectedText

        tot = tou

        RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(tou, "")
        tot = tot.ToUpper
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(tot)
```

can any one tell where i am wrong and tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the selected text and then convert it to upper case:

```
Dim toUpper As String = RichTextBox1.SelectedText.ToUpper
```

If you want to set the selected text to upper case:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = RichTextBox1.SelectedText.ToUpper
```